# perf top command only works on core 0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64, perf

I'm working on an arm64 (Cortex-A72 * 4) machine, running 4.19.139 kernel.

Currently, the perf top command only works with core 0.

Details:

1. `perf top -C 0` works as expected
2. `perf top -C 1` shows only header, while there is programs running on core 1. It does not print any errors. Example:

```
   PerfTop:       0 irqs/sec  kernel: 0.0%  exact:  0.0% [1000Hz cycles:ppp],  (all, CPU: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3. `perf top` shows same result as `perf top -C 0`, that is only results from core 0 were shown.
4. `perf top -t [tid-of-a-thread-binds-on-core-1]` shows empty result
5. `perf top -t [tid-of-a-thread-binds-on-core-0]` works as expected

What I have tried:

1. PMU driver seems loaded, as kmesg says: `hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available`
2. `perf` seems able to detect device's cpu count, as `perf stat` shows correct cpu count (4)
3. `perf --version` shows same version as kernel, that is 4.19.139

What should I do to fix/further investigate this issue?

Comment: Have you tried it with a version 5 or 6 kernel?  It could be a bug whose fix was never backported.

Comment: @NateEldredge Not yet. Porting newer kernels to the device seems beyond my skill level. I've tried to search changelogs but have no luck. Not sure it is issue with my searching skill or there is simply no such fix.